# user program not recognized by simulate command in Stata

Tags: stata, simulate

I have written a tiny program for simulation of multiple regression results. I can run this on a line by line basis (using actual values instead of the syntax command), but when I put it in an ado, it doesn't work properly.

The basic idea is use `drawnorm` to generate a dataset, run regression on it, then do it over and over using the `simulate` option. I am using a single command line `[powersim3, ry1(.30) ry2(.30) r12 (.30) n (282)] to run the syntax below (encased in the *****)`.

```
******
 program define powersim3, rclass
 syntax, ry1(real)ry2(real)r12(real)n(
real) [my(real 0)m1(real
0)m2(real 0)m3(real 0)sy(real 1) ///
    s1(real 1)s2(real 1)s3(real 1)alpha(real .05)help]
matrix m = (`my', `m1', `m2')
matrix sd = (`sy', `s1', `s2')
matrix r = (1, `ry1', `ry2'\ `ry1' , 1 , `r12'\ `ry2' , `r12', 1)
drawnorm y x1 x2, n(`n') corr(r) means(m) sds(sd)
regress y x1 x2
end

simulate _b _se, reps(10000): powersim3
*****
```

It appears the issue is that the `simulate` command isn't recognizing the `powersim3` command above (this works if you leave simulate out). I expect there is a simple solution here -- but I'm not proficient enough in Stata to know what the simple answer is. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: I think you need to use `eclass` not `rclass` . Details [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/bootstrapping-vectors/)

Comment: eclass provides the same error messages. Also, this is not a problem that I want to apply bootstrap to. I want a new random sample from the population each time as this will more correctly estimate the underlying construct (Power)

Comment: Cross-posted to Statalist. Better to declare that explicitly.

Comment: My apologies re: Statalist. Is there a way to delete those messages? The interface here is far simpler.

Comment: You are getting better attention on Statalist. There is no deletion retrospectively there: see http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/statalist-faq/#comment But if you prefer this forum, don't post on Statalist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

1. Your program `powersim3` requires the options `ry1()`, `ry2()`,  `r12()`, and `n()`. In your call to `simulate` you omitted those options.
2. Your program must start by deleting the variables y x1 x2; otherwise it will return errors on the second iteration and later as it then tries to `generate` variables that already exist.
3. The `syntax` statement contains various problems with spaces being left out.

Fixing all that, a working example is:

```
clear all
program define powersim3, rclass
    syntax, ry1(real) ry2(real) r12(real) n(real) ///
    [ my(real 0) m1(real 0) m2(real 0) m3(real 0) sy(real 1) ///
    s1(real 1) s2(real 1) s3(real 1) alpha(real .05)]

    drop _all

    tempname m sd r
    matrix `m' = (`my', `m1', `m2')
    matrix `sd' = (`sy', `s1', `s2')
    matrix `r' = (1, `ry1', `ry2'\ `ry1' , 1 , `r12'\ `ry2' , `r12', 1)
    drawnorm y x1 x2, n(`n') corr(`r') means(`m') sds(`sd')
    regress y x1 x2
end

simulate _b _se, reps(10000): ///
    powersim3, ry1(.30) ry2(.30) r12(.30) n(282)
```

---

**Edit**

In order to package that entire process in one command you need to store two .ado files: powersim3.ado and powersim3_simulator.ado. The former is the command that the user calls and the latter is the command that `simulate` calls within `powersim3`. Since `powersim3` will erase all data currently in memory and replaces it with the results from the simulation, I insist that the user specifies the `clear` option. This safeguard is convention in the Stata world. I added an option `reps()` such that the user can specify the number of replications. The remaining options are captured by the `*` in the `syntax` command of `powersim3`. This means that whatever other options the user specifies are stored in the local macro `` `options' ``. These options are all passed on to the `powersim3_simulator` command.

*--- begin file powersim3.ado

```
program define powersim3
    syntax , clear [ reps(integer 100) * ]
    simulate _b _se, reps(`reps') : powersim3_simulator, `options'
end
```

*--- end file powersim3.ado

*--- begin file powersim3_simulator.ado

```
program define powersim3_simulator
    syntax, ry1(real) ry2(real) r12(real) n(real)                ///
        [ my(real 0) m1(real 0) m2(real 0) m3(real 0) sy(real 1) ///
        s1(real 1) s2(real 1) s3(real 1) alpha(real .05)]

    drop _all

    tempname m sd r
    matrix `m' = (`my', `m1', `m2')
    matrix `sd' = (`sy', `s1', `s2')
    matrix `r' = (1, `ry1', `ry2'\ `ry1' , 1 , `r12'\ `ry2' , `r12', 1)
    drawnorm y x1 x2, n(`n') corr(`r') means(`m') sds(`sd')
    regress y x1 x2
end
```

*--- end file powersim3_simulator.ado

---

`powersim3_simulator` is just a helper program, and often you can add helper programs in the same .ado file, something like so

*--- begin foo.ado file

```
program define foo
    ...
    bar
    ...
end

program define bar
    ...
end
```

*--- end foo.ado file

This is convenient as it reduces the number of files necessary for a program, but this won't work in this case. The reason is that the program `bar` (or in your case `powersim3_simulator`) will be local to the program `foo` (or in your case `powersim3`), which means `simulate` won't be able to find it. So for this problem you really need to store two .ado files to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your work on this. The code above does run but it is not exactly what I was after. My desire is to set the entire piece -- from clear all through simulate to run using a single, user provided command line (e.g., powersim3, ry1(.30) ry2(.30) r12(.30) n(282)). My intention is to capture the rest in an ado file.

Comment: @ChrisAberson OK, I think I understand the question now. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and generosity. Greatly appreciated.